# Problem with reset state function and only than fetching data (React hooks)

Tags: javascript, react-redux

I am showing a list of users(profiles), and fetch it from some users DB.
I am in the search page which include sub pages for diffrenet filters - like which users are currently online.
Each time i am moving inside the search sub pages, i have to reset only once the main filtering variable in order ot get the correct result.
The problem is the fetch request happpend before the setState variable changed.
I saw other people asked how to fetch after, while i need it to first reset the variables of setState and the to go and fetch according to the correct values.

### code:

```
const [isPopUpShowState,setIsPopUpShowState] = useState(false);        
const [profilesloading,setProfilesLoading] = useState(<Spinner/>);          
const [profilesLength,setProfilesLength] = useState(0);    
const [profilesPerPage] = useState(4);                      
const [searchStartPoint,setSearchStartPoint] = useState(0); 
const [lastUserConnIndex,setLastUserConnIndex] = useState(1);   

       
useEffect( ()=> {
    restoreStatesToDefault();  // reset states+list  --> the variables doesnt changed before the the fetch       
       
   getProfilesMatchingPage(); // init profiles
},[history.location.pathname]);

const restoreStatesToDefault = () => {               
    list = {};
    setSearchStartPoint(0);
    setLastUserConnIndex(1);                            
    setProfilesLength(0);        
}

const getSearchProfilesParmsInObj = () => {
   const parmsObj = {};
   if(currUser.loginObj){            
     parmsObj['isMale'] = !currUser.loginObj.data.isMale;
     parmsObj['profilesPerPage'] = profilesPerPage;           
     parmsObj['searchStartPoint'] = searchStartPoint;
     parmsObj['lastUserConnIndex'] = lastUserConnIndex;            
     parmsObj['allProfiles'] = list;
    }
    return parmsObj;
}

    const getProfilesMatchingPage = () => {
           
            switch(history.location.pathname){
                case '/search/online':                              
                    dispatch(getProfilesOnline(getSearchProfilesParmsInObj(),setProfilesLoading,setLastUserConnIndex,setProfilesLength));
                    break;            
                case '/search/pics':
                    dispatch(getProfilesOnlyWithPics(getSearchProfilesParmsInObj(),setProfilesLoading,setLastUserConnIndex,setSearchStartPoint,setProfilesLength));  
                    break;
                case '/search/recently':
                    dispatch(getProfilesRecentlyVisited(getSearchProfilesParmsInObj(),setProfilesLoading,setLastUserConnIndex,setSearchStartPoint,setProfilesLength));  
                    break;
                case '/search/news':
                    dispatch(getProfilesNewUsersRegistered(getSearchProfilesParmsInObj(),setProfilesLoading,setLastUserConnIndex,setSearchStartPoint,setProfilesLength));        
            }
    }
```

Comment: i have another bug which i hope u can help with

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that both functions are called within the same lifecycle of the function, so the states haven't updated yet (They are within the same `closure`). After your `useEffect` finishes, then the next render is called with the updated state values, but they are not dependencies of your `useEffect` so they don't trigger it to fire again (which is a good thing in this case).

Basically what you want is two `useEffect` -> one is triggered on path change,  and that one should update state that is a dependency of another useEffect that triggers the fetch.

A simple example would be:

```
const [shouldFetch, setShouldFetch] = useState(false) // Set this to true if you want to fetch on initial render
useEffect( ()=> {
    restoreStatesToDefault();  // reset states+list  --> the variables doesnt changed before the the fetch       
    setShouldFetch(true);
},[history.location.pathname]);

useEffect(() => {
    if (shouldFetch) {
        setShouldFetch(false);
        getProfilesMatchingPage(); // init profiles
    }
}, [shouldFetch])
```